# Interpreting int as char: is this a case of UB?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

I've found this code in a student program, which was converting digits from a string into their corresponding values:

```c
int temp2 = s[i];
int temp = strtol(&temp2, NULL, 10);
```

It's definitely not a good example of C programming and I've already listed many better alternatives.

The question is if, assuming a little endian architecture, this is guaranteed to always work or not. I'm inclined to say that this type punning <s>(int -> char*)</s> (int -> char) is UB, but is there any other case in which this would fail, excluding big endian CPUs?

Comment: It looks like strict aliasing does not apply here, as any object can be aliased with `char *`. I think it isn't UB but implementation defined behavior. Sure there are other things to be wary of. For example that this memory when reinterpreted has the string terminator character.

Comment: To be pedantic, you do not interpret a `int` as a `char*`. `&temp2` is an `int*`, not an `int`. That is a big difference.

Comment: Seems legal on a little-endian machine. Tad overkilly with a `strtol` for a single digit. Maybe the more interesting question is can the student explain how and why this works?

Comment: The punning is `int` to `char`, not to `char *`. `char *` is the type passed to `strtol`, not the type of the lvalue `strtol` uses for access. The C standard does not explicitly say `strtol` uses `char` as the lvalue for access, but it is reasonable to take it as such, or similar such as `unsigned char`. Since you add the assumption that `int` is little-endian, the behavior is defined as far as the `strtol` call is concerned.

Comment: It would be UB if `sizeof(int) == 1`.

Comment: Char is (often) signed, if there are any characters with a negative value, this would blow up (sign extension to int -> nul terminator gone). Is your input restricted to only digits?

Comment: @teapot418: OP asserts the student is converting digits, implying `s[i]` contains a single digit character, which must have a positive value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If `sizeof(int)` is 1 then the `int` is a single byte (a C byte can be more than 8 bits wide), but there would be no room for a null terminator, hence it would be UB. Byte order is irrelevant for a single byte value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I disagree. It could be a little-endian architecture where `sizeof(long) > 1 && sizeof(int) == 1`. (OP's conditions do not preclude that.)

Comment: Since we're assuming a particular endianness, may we also assume `sizeif(int) > sizeof(char)` so we can ignore all this `sizeof(int) == 1` silliness?

Comment: @Barmar OP can specify `sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)` as another condition if they want, but they specifically asked for "any other case in which this would fail, excluding big endian CPUs". My original comment, "It would be UB if `sizeof(int) == 1`" was only intended to point out a case where it would fail. I didn't intend for it to sprawl out into a long discussion. :-)

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you! That is exactly something I was looking for. I (wrongly) assumed that `sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)` was a requirement for C.

Comment: @teapot418 Thank you! It's absolutely an overkill, and the input was guaranteed to be base 10 digits. But still, not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Again, thank you for the type punning details.